# Registration options and approvals

Tags: user-registration

What are the possible registration options in Wordpress (everybody can register, nobody can register, only some users can register)?

More specifically:

- can Wordpress be setup so that only those users that are previously approved are registered?
- can registrations by users be prevented altogether so that all registrations are done by the administrator?
- can all readers who wish so be registered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ["Settings > General" Screen](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_General_Screen) has a checkbox for "anyone can register." This answers your second and third questions - it depends on how that setting is set.

For your first question, that functionality is not built into WordPress. Perhaps a plugin like [WP User Registration](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-password-register/) would suit your needs for this bit of functionality.

Good luck!

Comment: As I understand from your answer, the opposite of "anyone can register" for Wordpress means "nobody can register"? Thank you for the plugin suggestion!

Comment: Yes, if "Anyone can register" is unchecked, adding users (along with other user capabilities defined here http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Roles) can only be done by an administrator.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much, that answers my question.